# How to make autocomplete not change already-typed path?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I got my zsh autocompletion working the way I wanted a while ago, with one exception I just noticed.

If there is two empty directories looking like this:
`a/b/` and `a1/b/c`
and I `cd a/b/` and tab to see more, there is nothing more, so autocomplete automatically switches to `a1/b/c`, which almost caused me to overwrite files in the wrong directory.

My current autocomplete section in .zshrc looks like this:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zmodload zsh/complist
compinit
_comp_options+=(globdots)
```

What do I have to change to just forbid autocomplete to change directories I already typed / selected but keep the rest of my current autocomplete config in tact?

A nudge in the direction of the part of the documentation where I could have found this myself would be much appreciated, I don't seem to be able to find it for the life of me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on the [`accept-exact-dirs` completion style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-accept_002dexact_002ddirs_002c-completion-style).

```
zstyle :completion::complete:cd::paths accept-exact-dirs true
```

How to find this empirically: turn on traces (`set -x`), then enter `cd a/b/` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. In the trace, find where `a1` is first mentioned, then look before. This sort of sensible configuration option usually exists as a [style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System-Configuration-1) which can be configured with [`zstyle`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zstyle).